# Where clause returning values outside range

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am trying to get pre-determined results on a homework problem for a SQL intro class.

"Write a query to display the book number, title, subject, and cost for all books that are on the subjects of “Middleware” or “Cloud”, and that cost should be more than $70 sorted by book number."

The query I last tried returns almost correct results, but includes books with a book cost of 69.95.

```sql
SELECT BOOK_NUM, BOOK_TITLE, BOOK_SUBJECT, BOOK_COST
FROM BOOK
WHERE BOOK_COST > 70 AND BOOK_SUBJECT = 'Middleware' 
      OR BOOK_SUBJECT = 'Cloud'
ORDER BY BOOK_NUM;
```

I tried increasing the value to 70.01 and placing quotations around the 70 and parenthesis such as:

```sql
WHERE (BOOK_COST > 70) 
AND BOOK_SUBJECT = 'Middleware' OR BOOK_SUBJECT = 'Cloud'
ORDER BY BOOK_NUM;
```

Any feedback would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Use parentheses for your boolean expressions so they evaluate how you intend them to.  That will fix your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need parenthesis to separate your `WHERE` clause. Try:

`WHERE BOOK_COST > 70 AND ( BOOK_SUBJECT = 'Middleware' OR BOOK_SUBJECT = 'Cloud' )`

**Explanation**:

The query is split by the `OR` so it actually means: `WHERE (BOOK_COST > 70 AND BOOK_SUBJECT = 'Middleware') OR (BOOK_SUBJECT = 'CLOUD')`. This will return any book subject of CLOUD regardless of cost. Hope that helps.

Comment: Also - ```BOOK_SUBJECT in ('Middleware', 'Cloud')```

Answer (score 2):

Better use IN Clause as its similar to OR.

```
.... where  BOOK_SUBJECT IN 
      ('Middleware', 
    'Cloud') and book_cost>70
```